# How to implement an interactive regplot using plotly in streamlit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python, streamlit

I have a [sample dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SRxq.png) which contains columns named 'Likes' and 'Views'. I want to implement a interactive regplot between 'Likes' and 'Views' and render it into streamlit.
Is there any way to implement regplot using plotly, i already know how to implement regplot with seaborn but i want to make it interactive by implementing with plotly.

I have tried using a scatter plot in the way mentioned below

```
fig = px.scatter(data,x = 'Likes',y= 'Views', trendline='ols',trendline_color_override='red')
st.pyplot(fig)
```

But it is generating an error
"Figure" attribute has no attribute "savefig"

I am expecting a way to plot a regplot using plotly to render it into streamlit web app

Comment: Use `st.plotly_chart(fig)`.